# How can I see the current upload and download speed on my iPhone that is caused by sharing Internet to another device via Bluetooth tethering?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, internet, tethering, monitoring

I share Internet on my iPhone via Bluetooth tethering to some Android phone. How can I see the current upload and download speed (i.e., monitoring the current use) on my iPhone that is caused by the Bluetooth tethering?